# LEFT JOIN BETWEEN TWO TABLES

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables X AND Y.i Have two coloumns in table X namely A and B and coloumn C in table Y.
Now i want to join X and Y using Left join With ON Condition 
X.a=y.c or X.b=y.c.  I want to get rows for 'c' coloumn in table Y with respective to rows for 'a 'coloumn in table X and 'c' cOLOUMN in table Y with respective to rows for B'coloumn in table X .

Result should be like :

```
-----------------------
X.a    Y.C          X.B       Y.C
1       1            5         5
2       2            10        10
3       3            20        20 
NULL     NULL        NULL      NULL
```

Comment: Show me what you have so far?

Comment: select o.FKYS_COMBO_ID,o.FKYS_MOP1,o.FKYS_MOP2,i.KYS_ID ,i.BOL_HARD_COPY_CLAIM,pa.FKYS_COMBO_ID from mt_cmn_order o
left join cmn_insurance i on (o.FKYS_MOP1=i.KYS_ID  or o.FKYS_MOP2=i.KYS_ID )

Comment: What is your question? Show your data. Show your query. Show your wrongfulness results. Create a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this

```sql
SELECT x.a, y1.c ac, x.b, y2.c bc
  FROM x 
    LEFT JOIN y y1 ON x.a = y1.c 
    LEFT JOIN y y2 ON x.b = y2.c
```

Sample output:

```
|      A |     AC |      B |     BC |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|      1 |      1 |      5 |      5 |
|      2 |      2 |     10 |     10 |
|      3 |      3 |     20 |     20 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a27d/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT X.a, X.b, Y.c
FROM X LEFT JOIN Y
ON X.a = Y.c OR X.b = Y.c
```

Where's your problem ?

Is the problem not knowing sql syntax ? otherwise you're probably not framing your problem statement correctly

---

Based on your comment I'm going with the assumption that you want to know for which match is the value being retrieved and the modified query is :

```
SELECT X.a, X.b, Y.c, 
CASE WHEN (X.a = Y.c AND X.b != Y.c) THEN 'a' 
WHEN (X.a != Y.c AND X.b = Y.c) THEN 'b' 
WHEN (X.a = Y.c AND X.b = Y.c) THEN 'ab' END AS 'FromColumn'
FROM X LEFT JOIN Y
ON X.a = Y.c OR X.b = Y.c
```

Comment: I want two y.c columns in the result separately for respective X.a and X.b  values

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me, the value will always be the same. Also if you end up processing the table in lets say .net, the two columns with the same name will create problems when you reference the cell values using the column name. By any chance do you want to know if the value is retrieved for a or b ?

Comment: yeah exactly i need that